# Web with dynamic ad display based on owner of context?

Tags: javascript, content-management-system, admob, social-networking, adsense

Im trying to design a good Monetization logic!

Let's say I build a blog(example: hypotheticalblogname.com). It allows users to register and write articles, just as any other blog system.

The system/web allows you to make an article search which delivers a list of articles. Now when the user that made the search clicks on a given article the web will display the whole article in detail:(hypotheticalblogname.com/detailview/articleId)

On the detail view among the content of the article(description text, images, video...) I want to display ads(I want a given % of the ad revenue to go to the creator of the article and part of the % to the web site).

Best practice for a system like this? Here are the options I am trying to figure out if are right or not:

A-I could ask the users that create articles to enlist in adsense and submit me publisherId and slotId and x% of displays of the article use our publisherId and other % the articles creator publisherId?

B-I could always use the websites own publisherId and at the end of the month payout to all the article creators their cut based on our own logic(up votes, n° visualisations of article...)

Ideally Id like to be able to add ads to video content as well  but this is complicated because of googles policy on how to monetise video content hosted on youtube....

What is the best option for a system like this. Use our own publisherId, users publisherId plus ours, is adsense the best option, are there better ad networks out there that fit our needs better?

Any guidance will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Adsense Host Program/API is a dedicated way of doing that: https://developers.google.com/adsense/host/?hl=en

Comment: That is very nice but...!

Comment: Only websites with over 100,000 daily page views are eligible to participate in the AdSense Host API program. If your site does not meet this requirement, you can still monetize your site by using Google AdSense.

Comment: This is highlighted on the front page!

Comment: Does your question mention traffic on the website?

Comment: No it does not. That is the reason for my former comments. Now that I read them, weird way of mine to explain I don't meet those requirements, and ask for an alternative...

Answer (score 1):

I have some experience in those kind of monetization systems and for a MVP I would hardly recommend you to choose the first option since it will be easier to integrate and it will save you a lot of trouble related to payments and other legal issues.

Once you already have your product running and you can dedicate time and resources only for the payment system you should study other options like creating your own mediation system so you can find better deals for your users and also take a mediation commission and increase your revenue.